# How to upload a full-stack (ReactJS , NodeJS , socketIO) project to github by git bash command line

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, express, socket.io

I have just built a project about realtime chat , now I just want to upload it to the github reposity
my folder structure look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4TYK.jpg)

I don't know how to upload the whole project to github by git bash command line

I have read the github docs , but I just can only upload 1 folder per time (just "client" or "server" folder per time) , can someone show me how to upload the whole folder (the "chat-app" folder) to github?

Comment: You have to initiate git or say git init in your parent most directory in which different folders for different project and you have to commit and  push from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, be sure that your gitignore contains the following :

`/node_modules`

It will prevent git from uploading node_module (which you can easily recreate with `npm install`).

- Then you can do a `git init` in your folder (chat-app). It will create a new **local Git repository**.

you can then use the full power of git in this folder.

- Then you have to add modificated files to **stage**. many possibilities here some uses `git add .` or `git add -A` or you can do it file by file `git add [filename]` (Without brackets)
- After that you can **commit** your modification with a **message** to tell what modifications you made : `git commit -m "my super commit message"`
- You also have to specify git a **remote repository** `git remote add [name] [url]` (for exemple : `git remote add github http://github.com/myUsername/myRepo.git`
- And finally you can **push** your modification : `git push [remoteName] [remoteBranch]` (`git push github master`)